# Is there an equivalent Larmor precession that is non-magnetic in nature?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, material-science, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Can the magnetic moment of a particle be manipulated without magnetic fields? Could one accomplish this with electromagnetic radiation or even "Atom Lasers"?

Comment: Electromagnetic radiation has a magnetic field.

Comment: That is indeed true, however the magnetic component of an electromagnetic wave is extremely weak. There is a reason solar panels use the electric field vector of light when in operation.